# Why does creating an array in storage within a method change the state for something else?

Tags: solidity, testing, storage, arrays

I have a simple contract that sets an `owner` when the contract is initialized, but am having trouble understanding why it changes under certain circumstances.

I tried 3 ways of initializing and setting an array:

1. Using an array in memory
2. Defining a storage array outside of a method and pushing to it
3. Defining a storage array within a method and pushing to it

Cases 1 and 2 behave as expected, but Case 3 ends up changing the `owner` value and causes tests to fail. Can anyone provide insight on this behavior?

Smart contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract WeirdCase {

    address internal owner;
    uint256[] newArray;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function someMethod1() external {
        uint256[] memory newArray = new uint256[](10);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            newArray[i] = i;
        }
    }

    function someMethod2() external {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            newArray.push(i);
        }
    }

    function someMethod3() external {
        uint256[] storage weirdArray;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            weirdArray.push(i);
        }
    }

    function getOwner() view returns(address) {
        return owner;
    }
}
```

Test case:

```
var WeirdCase = artifacts.require("./WeirdCase.sol");

contract('WeirdCase', function(accounts) {

  let weirdCase;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    weirdCase = await WeirdCase.new();
  });


  it("Case 1: succeeds", async function () {
    let beforeOwner = await weirdCase.getOwner();
    await weirdCase.someMethod1();

    let afterOwner = await weirdCase.getOwner();
    assert.equal(beforeOwner, afterOwner);
  });

  it("Case 2: succeeds", async function () {
    let beforeOwner = await weirdCase.getOwner();
    await weirdCase.someMethod2();

    let afterOwner = await weirdCase.getOwner();
    assert.equal(beforeOwner, afterOwner);
  });

  /*
   * DON'T KNOW WHY THIS FAILS!!!
   */
  it("Case 3: not sure why this fails", async function () {
    let beforeOwner = await weirdCase.getOwner();
    await weirdCase.someMethod3();

    let afterOwner = await weirdCase.getOwner();
    assert.equal(beforeOwner, afterOwner);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is the key:

```
uint256[] storage weirdArray;
```

You're defining `weirdArray` as a pointer to an array in storage, but you never point it to any array in storage. Therefore, the `weirdArray` array pointer is initialized as `0x00`.

This causes the `.push()` to write to storage location `0x00`, because the `push` method thinks that that's where the array is stored. `0x00` happens to be where the compiler placed your `owner` state variable.

Comment: That makes sense... I guess i need to rethink how to when/how to use dynamic arrays or arrays in memory.

Thanks a bunch!